# Array Prop Undefined - Mapping Array In Props

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I am expecting to map over an array, and pass the data to a child component. The undesired outcome is it reads as `undefined`.

**Parent Component:**

```
import Tier from "./tier";
const data = [
  {
    title: "SAVER SALLY",
    subtitle: "22,000rmb/month",
    list: [
      "Income Tax: 3,295",
      "Income Tax: 3,295",
    ],
    bottom: {
      title: "Total Yearly Savings:",
      centralNumber: "144,480RMB",
      subtitle: "This is approximately £16,000 or 21,000USD",
    },
  }
];

const Tiers = ({ classes }) => {
    return (
        <>
        {data.map(set => <Tier objectInformation={set} />)}
        </>
    )
}

export default withStyles((theme) => ({}))(Tiers);
```

**The Child Component:**

```
const Tier = ({ classes, objectInformation }) => {
  const {title, subtitle, list, bottom} = objectInformation 
  console.log("OBJECT INFORMATION", objectInformation)
  return (
    <div>{title}</div> 
  )
}
```

The end goal is to have multiple objects in the data variable, that'll pass down as props to `Tiers`, the parents component.

Comment: Try to declare your `data` array inside of the `Tiers` component.

Comment: @LukeP What is the output of this console ..  
console.log("OBJECT INFORMATION", objectInformation)

Comment: @KhandkerAshikMahmud, it is `OBJECT INFORMATION undefined`. Thanks for reaching out!

Answer (score 0):

You can't render an object within a component in React.

Either stringify your object

```
    const Tier = ({ classes, objectInformation }) => {
      return (
        <div>{JSON.stringify(objectInformation)}</div> 
      )
    }
```

or only select a part of it.

```
    const Tier = ({ classes, objectInformation }) => {
      return (
        <div>{objectInformation.title}</div> 
      )
    }
```

Comment: I thought that the problem was on the `console.log`, I did not seen this...

Comment: @BaptisteRieber, the issue on the `console.log`, as it logs `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I missed an `s` on the imports.

**Incorrect**: `import Tiers from "components/tiers/tier"`

**Correct**: `import Tiers from "components/tiers/tiers"`

Changing this fixed the issue.